# Spring Tool Suite (version 3.9./1) will not load

Tags: spring, jvm

Just installed `Spring Tool Suite` version 3.9.1.  On trying to execute `STS.exe`, I get a message

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"

I have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin` at the start of my path environment variable, and verifield that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\server` contains `jvm.dll`.  Any ideas on why else it will not load?

Comment: Do you use Eclipse IDE along with your STS? If you do, please check that Eclipse is 64-bit application, not 32-bit

Comment: Yes, it is the 64 bit version.  I did download the 3.8.4 release, and have been having no problems running it.